# How does one make a transition for removing a div completely, not just visibility?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

How do I make it so that when you hover, the original div goes away completely, not just the visibility and it has a transition in doing so and the new div doesn't show up until the transition is done? Using javascript is fine.

I know that using display doesn't allow for a transition, but it's the only thing I could think of and gives a good idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="square">
   <div class="title">Title</div>
   <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.square{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: lightblue;
}
  .content{
        display: none;
}
  .square:hover .content{
        display: block;
}
  .square:hover .title{
        display: none;
        transition-duration: 800ms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `opacity` to hide the title but it would still be there. Add `click-event: none` to it so that it would be invisible as well as non-clickable.

Or you can use the `transform: translate()` to make the title move away with the transition. Add these lines (commented) to your code:

```css
.square{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: lightblue;
        position: relative;
}
  .content{
        display: none;
        /*starts here*/
        position: absolute; /* If you want to position the content exactly under the title*/
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        /*ends here*/
}
  .square:hover .content{
        transform: translateX(0); /*Add here*/
        display: block;
}
  .square:hover .title{
        transform: translateX(-100%); /*Add here*/
        transition-duration: 800ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
   <div class="title">Title</div>
   <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```